# Picking teams of students from a classroom

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-distributions

There are $20$ male and $15$ female students in a classroom. We randomly pick $3$ groups of $4$ students each. What's the probability of having at least $2$ groups of $3$ male and $1$ female student each?

If we picked only $1$ group we would use the hypergeometric distribution, but how are we going to calculate the probability of $3$ samples? I also tried to use conditional probabilities but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Against a total sample space of $\dbinom{35}4\dbinom{31}4\dbinom{27}4 = D\;$, say,

ways of choosing at least $2$ groups of needed composition = $\dbinom{20}3\dbinom{15}1\dbinom{17}3\dbinom{14}1\dbinom{27}{4}$

thus, $Pr = \dfrac{\dbinom{20}3\dbinom{15}1\dbinom{17}3\dbinom{14}1\dbinom{27}{4}}{D}$

*Note:* Think of it as analogous to distributing cards.